# Removing from self joining type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

Whenever I want to remove hierarchy of objects meaning a `Menu` object containing another `Menu` object in it. But it works fine if single object is removed (without any object inside). I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

This is what my type looks like:

```
 public class Menu
    {
        public string Reference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        [MaxLength(30), MinLength(2)]
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string HyperLink { get; set; }

        private List<Menu> menus;
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public virtual List<Menu> Menus
        {
            get 
            {
                if (menus == null || menus.Count == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return menus;
            }
            set { menus = value; }
        }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().HasKey(k => k.Reference);
   }
```

Following is how I am removing:

```
List<Menu> menu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TMenu>>(Menu);

            using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
            {
                if (context.Menus.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in menu)
                    {
                        Menu deleteMenu = context.Menus.Where(f => f.Reference == item.Reference).FirstOrDefault();
                        context.Menus.Remove(deleteMenu);
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

I would really appreciate a suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, SQL Server cannot do recursive delete even though PostGres can I read. Anyway, I had to create a trigger on the table where recursive delete was manually made.